# ios Share document into NativeScript app with CFBundleDocumentTypes

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I want to open/share/send documents into my NativeScript app

for example (non NativeScript): 
https://coderwall.com/p/83djxa/registering-your-app-to-be-able-to-open-images-from-other-apps

There is an android example here:  [Can I share to my NativeScript app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515098/can-i-share-to-my-nativescript-app)

Is this possible for iOS NativeScript? (will ultimately want it both android and iOS)

Comment: This is a good idea for a nativescript plugin.  I did a quick search could not find anything.

Comment: does https://github.com/tjvantoll/nativescript-social-share plugin works for your case

Comment: @NikolayTsonev that is for sharing content out of a nativescript app, I am looking to share into nativescript app

Comment: @DanBlack : Have you implemented this in your Nativescript app ? Please share more information about this. I would like to implement similar. but I did not find much information.